# Zoom Control which is part of WPF Extensions available on Codeplex

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

The zoom control found at http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/ is something that I would like to use in my project.  However, there is one feature I wish it had.  I would like for it to work with a ScrollViewer so that if the contents are zoomed in, the scrollbars would activate (if necessary).

The control's template is defined in Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ZoomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:ZoomControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"                                
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="Green"
                                ClipToBounds="{TemplateBinding ClipToBounds}">
                            <Controls:ZoomContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Presenter"
                                                           ClipToBounds="False" />
                        </Border>
                        <Canvas>

                            <!-- Controls -->
                            <Border Padding="5"
                                    CornerRadius="5"
                                    Background="#88C0C0C0"
                                    Canvas.Left="20"
                                    Canvas.Top="20"
                                    ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0">
                                <Border.ToolTip>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock><Run FontWeight="Bold">CTRL + Wheel:</Run> Zoom In / Out</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock><Run FontWeight="Bold">ALT + Drag:</Run> ZoomBox</TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock><Run FontWeight="Bold">(SHIFT +) Drag:</Run> Pan</TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border.ToolTip>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                                        <Border x:Name="border"
                                                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                Background="Silver"
                                                                BorderThickness="1"
                                                                CornerRadius="5"
                                                                Width="40"
                                                                Height="40"
                                                                Margin="2"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                        </Border>

                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                                     Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                                                        Property="Background"
                                                                        Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                                                     Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                                                        Property="Background"
                                                                        Value="DarkGray" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                                                        Property="TextBlock.FontWeight"
                                                                        Value="Bold" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                                    <Slider Height="150"
                                            Minimum="{TemplateBinding MinZoom,Converter={StaticResource log10Converter}}"
                                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding MaxZoom,Converter={StaticResource log10Converter}}"
                                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Zoom,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource log10Converter}}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            Ticks="0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 2"
                                            AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"
                                            AutoToolTipPrecision="1"
                                            TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                                            TickFrequency="1"
                                            LargeChange="1"
                                            SmallChange="0.1"
                                            Orientation="Vertical" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Zoom,StringFormat='{}{0:F2}x'}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               FontWeight="Bold" />
                                    <RadioButton Content="1:1"
                                                 GroupName="rbgZoomMode"
                                                 IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Mode,Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static Controls:ZoomControlModes.Original}}" />
                                    <RadioButton Content="Fill"
                                                 GroupName="rbgZoomMode"
                                                 IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Mode,Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static Controls:ZoomControlModes.Fill}}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>

                            <!-- ZoomBox -->
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding ZoomBoxBorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding ZoomBoxBorderThickness}"
                                    Canvas.Left="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ZoomBox.X}"
                                    Canvas.Top="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ZoomBox.Y}"
                                    Opacity="{TemplateBinding ZoomBoxOpacity}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding ZoomBoxBackground}"
                                    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ZoomBox.Width}"
                                    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ZoomBox.Height}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="ZoomBoxBackground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.0, 0.0"
                                     EndPoint="1.0, 1.0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Silver"
                                  Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="DarkGray"
                                  Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ZoomBoxBorderBrush"
                Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="ZoomBoxBorderThickness"
                Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="ClipToBounds"
                Value="True" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ModifierMode"
                     Value="Pan">
                <Setter Property="Cursor"
                        Value="SizeAll" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ModifierMode"
                     Value="ZoomBox">
                <Setter Property="Cursor"
                        Value="Hand" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I tried adding ScrollViewer tags around the PART_Presenter but that caused the control to break (nothing was rendered).

Hopefully someone smarter than I am can help me out with this.  The control is not that complex but I am still learning WPF and especially templating.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going another route and using the zoom controls panning feature with slight modifications instead of trying to add scrollbars.